# How can I convert week format date to acceptable as.date in R for time series analysis?

Tags: r, data-science

I've tried many ways to convert this week format I've made to a passable format to set as.Date for time series analysis. In reality I wish to aggregate the raw data to weekly in R but I did it somewhere else and created the format:

```
"2021-W23"
```

These are the following codes I've tried:

```
as.Date(paste0(dataset_sales$weekyr, sep="-", 1), "%Y-W%U-%d")
```

Giving odly this result for all observations:
"2021-11-01"

Next, I tried

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(paste0(dataset_sales$weekyr, sep="-", 1),"%Y-%U-%d")
```

Obtaining

```
"2021-11-01 UTC"
```

Then:

```
strptime(dataset_sales$Weekyr, format= "%Y-W%W")
```

Obtaining same date for today...

```
"2019-11-18 CST"
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output was any date format admissible for time series analysis. I stayed with the one where i changed the date to the beginning of the week and i would sum the sales there.